# Use node-webkit to remote control an iframe?

Tags: node-webkit

I'm trying to automate a work flow where we have to log in to a website, navigate, get redirected several times and finally have to upload a file into a reporting system.

After failing with phantomjs/casparjs (where we also do not really get visual feedback) I was thinking about using node-webkit.

So basically, what I am trying to do is writing a "controller" that is opening another webpage in an iframe and then manipulating the fields, hitting buttons, ...

Is this something that can be done? If yes, I am struggeling to get a handle on the fields to fill them...

Or is this a classic "wrong tool" approach and we shouldn't be doing that?

Something along the line of

```
var new_win = gui.Window.get(
    window.open('https://remote/login/site/')
);

gui.Window.get(new_win).on('loaded', function () {
     //all of this doesn't really work but might help you to understand what I try to do

     //window.console.log(new_win.window.document.getElementById("user"));
     //window.eval(new_win, "code_to_fill_the_user_field");

     //var userField = new_win.window.document.getElementById("user");
     //console.log(userField);
});
```

**Update: 2014-08-02:**
I understand now that webkit is intended for creating desktop apps with HTML5 and not remote controlling websites, so we forget about this question.
I did solve the problem with phantomjs/casperjs now, BTW.

Comment: How did phantomjs fail? You should be able to handle any complex web browser related processing with it, as it is really little more than an instrumentable but chromeless browser instance.

Comment: Originally I failed when working with a file upload input field, but finally got it working with the latest versions. So, my process is automated now and works with phantom/casper, so I solved it with the original plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand now that node-webkit is intended for creating desktop apps with HTML5 and not remote controlling websites, so we forget about this question. I did manage to solve the problem with phantomjs/casperjs now.